# ormlite with persistent h2 db - new tables not get persisted

Tags: java, h2, ormlite

When I am creating a new H2 database via ORMLite the database file get created but after I close my application, all the data that it stored in the database is lost:

```
JdbcConnectionSource connection =
   new JdbcConnectionSource("jdbc:h2:file:" + path.getAbsolutePath() + ".h2.db");
TableUtils.createTable(connection, SomeClass.class);
Dao<SomeClass, Integer> dao = DaoManager.createDao(connection, SomeClass.class);
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass(id, ...);
dao.create(sc);
SomeClass retrieved = dao.queryForId(id);
System.out.println("" + retrieved);
```

This code will produce good results.  It will print the object that I stored.
But when I start the application again this time without creating the table and storing new object I get an exception telling me that the required table is not exists:

```
JdbcConnectionSource connection =
   new JdbcConnectionSource("jdbc:h2:file:" + path.getAbsolutePath() + ".h2.db");
Dao<SomeClass, Integer> dao = DaoManager.createDao(connection, SomeClass.class);
SomeClass  retrieved = dao.queryForId(id); // will produce an exception..
System.out.println("" + retrieved);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked fine for me if I ran it once and then a second time with the `createTable` turned off.  The 2nd insert gave me a primary key violation of course but that was expected.  It created the file with (as @Thomas mentioned) a ".h2.db.h2.db" prefix.

Some questions:

1. After you run your application the first time, can you see the `path` file being created?
2. Is it on permanent storage and not in some temporary location cleared by the OS?
3. Any chance some other part of your application is clearing it before the database code begins?

Hope this helps.

```
@Test
public void testStuff() throws Exception {
    File path = new File("/tmp/x");
    JdbcConnectionSource connection = new JdbcConnectionSource("jdbc:h2:file:"
        + path.getAbsolutePath() + ".h2.db");
    // TableUtils.createTable(connection, SomeClass.class);
    Dao<SomeClass, Integer> dao = DaoManager.createDao(connection,
        SomeClass.class);
    int id = 131233;
    SomeClass sc = new SomeClass(id, "fopewjfew");
    dao.create(sc);
    SomeClass retrieved = dao.queryForId(id);
    System.out.println("" + retrieved);
    connection.close();
}
```

I can see Russia from my house:

```
> ls -l /tmp/
...
-rw-r--r--  1 graywatson  wheel  14336 Aug 31 08:47 x.h2.db.h2.db
```

Comment: i can also see the file but in my version its empty
i created a new main with only this code and the result stay the same
- what version of h2 / ormlite are you using?

Comment: I'm using 4.25 of ORMLite and 1.2.128 of H2.  Maybe a stupid question but I assume you have enough disk space.  If the file is 0 length then something is very wrong.  What OS is this?

Comment: i running on windows 7 with the same versions as yours..
but still cant get it to work, i switch to javaDB and everything work fine with it - dont know what is the reason that the same code with H2 didnt work

Comment: Did my answer help at all @bennylu?

Answer (score 0):

Did you close the database? It is closed automatically but it's better to close it manually (so recovery is faster).

In many cases the database URL is the problem. Are you sure the same path is used in both cases? Otherwise you end up with two databases. By the way, ".h2.db" is added automatically, you don't need to add it manually.

To better analyze the problem, you could append `;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=2` to the database URL, and then check in the `*.trace.db` file what SQL statements were executed against the database.

Comment: i am closing the connection:
(connection.close)

im sure i using the same path.. 
i even printed it..